# Implement a fold-like Function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Let's say I need to write a function that applies a function to each item in a List, and then appends it to an accumulator. When the List is empty, return the accumulator.

```
go :: [a] -> (a -> [b]) -> [b] -> [b]
go [] f acc = acc
go (x:xs) f acc = go xs f (acc ++ f x)

myFold :: [a] -> (a -> [b]) -> [b]
myFold as f = go as f []
```

I used the `go` function so that I wouldn't force the `myFold` caller to have to provide an empty `[b]` type. Also, I used the `go` function to achieve tail recursion.

In Scala, I would've put `@annotation.tailrec` to make the compilation fail if the compiler could not perform tail-call optimization.

Is the above code idiomatic in Haskell?

Answer (score 2):

First, your function is `concatMap` from Prelude.

More idiomatic ways to write it:

```
myFold :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
myFold = concat . map
-- or
myFold f = foldr (\x acc -> (f x) ++ acc) []
```

If efficiency is a concern, it's a completely different question. Recommended steps in priority order:

1. Always compile at least with `-O2`
2. Lists are slow. `++` operation especially. Consider `Data.Sequence` or even `vector`s.
3. Avoid lazyness in your types
4. Provide all small functions with `INLINE` pragma.
5. And more...

Comment: I'm interested in readability for this question

Comment: Your second `myFold` concatenates the lists in reverse, and should probably [avoid use of foldl](http://www.well-typed.com/blog/90/).

Comment: @bisserlis you are right. Edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're definitely on the right track here for producing good Haskell code, assuming you're intentionally avoiding Prelude functions in favor of exercising other skills!

The very first thing I would change is the order of arguments in your `myFold` function (and by extension `go`), i.e., pass the function to map over the list in the first position. This can help you be terse when calling it elsewhere in your code. For instance, consider these two trivial definitions of the same identity function.

```
listid :: [a] -> [a]
listid as = myFold as (:[])

listid' = myFold' (:[]) -- Implies an instance of myFold w/ arguments flipped
```

The second definition is written in [pointfree](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree) style. This is considered good practice (in moderation) due to its emphasis on composing functionality over moving data around.

The next thing I would address is hiding your helper function `go` by making it locally defined in `myFold`.

```
myFold f as = go ...
    where go f as acc = ...
```

This has a few benefits.

1. If you're writing a library module here by default `go` will end up being exported to all of your users. Since this is an anonymous helper function, you probably don't want that.
2. Because again this is a one-shot helper function, locally defining it for `myFold` keeps it close to where it's used as opposed to floating around the top-level elsewhere.

That's about as idiomatic as you'll get without using Prelude functions. It is good to note however that your function is the composition of `concat` and `map`, and reusing functions from the Prelude is almost *always* better for readability.